# How to write a TypeScript function accepting a class implementing an interface as a parameter?

Tags: typescript, class, interface

I want to write a function which accepts a class as an argument, but only classes which `implement` a specific interface.

I know that I can use `any`, but it would be nice to rely on the type system to enforce this.

Some pseudocode to express what I mean...

```
interface MyInterface { ... }
class Class1 implements MyInterface { ... }
class Class2 { ... }

function doStuff(classParameter: Class implements MyInterface) { ... }
doStuff(Class1); // OK
doStuff(Class2); // Error
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a constructor signature to enforce the fact that the constructor will return an instance compatible with the interface. You can use it either as a generic parameter constraint or directly as a parameter depending on what you need to do with the class:

```
interface MyInterface { foo: number }
class Class1 implements MyInterface { foo: number }
class Class2 { bar: number }

function doStuff0(classParameter: new (...args: any[]) => MyInterface) { }
doStuff0(Class1); // OK
doStuff0(Class2); // Error

function doStuff1<T  extends new (...args: any[]) => MyInterface>(classParameter: T) {  }
doStuff1(Class1); // OK
doStuff1(Class2); // Error
```

**Note** I added members to the example, don't forget Typescript uses a structural type system, so compatibility is determined by members not by `implements MyInterface` declaration, so any class would be compatible if `MyInterface` were empty, and a class would be compatible if it had a `foo` member even if it didn't explicitly declare `implements MyInterface`

Comment: The second, generic example worked for me in the function signature, and I was able to use `new(...) => MyInterface` directly as a type in places where I referenced the class that was accepted as a function argument. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't `class Class2 { foo: number }` still pass the test ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use generics to achieve what you want to do. Here's a workaround :

```
function doStuff<T extends myInterface>(classParameter: T) {
  ...
}
```

So here, T is a dynamic type which necessary implements myInterface (yeah, keyword extends while talking about interfaces is strange here).

You can check the documentation below, part "Generic constraints"
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: The question is not about how to accept a parameter that implements `MyInterface` (which would be answered with just `function doStuff(x: MyInterface)`), but about how to refer to the type of a *constructor that produces* a `MyInterface`.  See @TitialCernicova-Dragomir's answer.

Comment: Hum, maybe I really don't get it, but it's not what I understand from Sophie's question... From the question :

"I want to write a function which accepts a class as an argument, but only classes which implement a specific interface."

Use generics really do the job, less rough than creating multiple constructors, for me. But ok, wait & see

Comment: She is passing the class to the function not an instance of it, ie `doStuff(Class1)` not `doStuff(new Class1())`. This could be a mistake, but I don't think so, she wants to pass in the class

Comment: Oh, I get it, indeed, I didn't understand the question. My bad :)